# Проблемы в коде при работе с txt файлами. <fstream>

Tags: c++, файлы, visual-c++

Такссс. Сразу к сути. Когда я пишу в файле am.in.txt 1 (Первый If) он выполняет условие (т.e.1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9 в файл am.out.txt пишет ), а когда я пишу 3 (Третьи If) он ничего не делает. Я проверил может что то с условием и написал в if-e: cout << "shit" << endl; он даже этого не делает (на тот момент у меня стоял system("pause");). Если кто-то нашел проблему, пожалуйста хелпаните. К слову я пробовал писать 4, то же самое.

```
ifstream ifn("am.in.txt", ios::in);
ofstream ofn("am.out.txt", ios::out);

int num;

if (!ifn.is_open())
{
    cout << "Weeelll... Shiiiit" << endl;
}
else
{
    ifn >> num;
    cout << num << endl;

    if (num > 5)
    {
        ofn << "nnnope" << endl;
    }

    if (num == 1)
    {
        ofn << "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9" << endl;
    }

    if (num == 2)
    {
        int a = 1, b = 0, c = 0;
        for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++)
        {
            c = pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2);
            if (c == i)
            {
                ofn << c << endl;
            }
            if (b == 10)
            {
                b = 0;
                a++;
            }
            b++;
        }

        if (num == 3)
        {
            int a = 1, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
            for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                c = pow(a, 3) + pow(b, 3) + pow(d, 3);
                if (c == i)
                {
                    ofn << c << endl;
                }
                if (d == 10)
                {
                    d = 0;
                    b++;
                }
                if (b == 10)
                {
                    b = 0;
                    a++;
                }
                d++;
            }
            ofn.close();
        }

        if (num == 4)
        {
            int a = 1, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0;
            for (int i = 1000; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                c = pow(a, 4) + pow(b, 4) + pow(d, 4) + pow(e, 4);
                if (c == i)
                {
                    ofn << c << endl;
                }
                if (e == 10)
                {
                    e = 0;
                    d++;
                }
                if (d == 10)
                {
                    d = 0;
                    b++;
                }
                if (b == 10)
                {
                    b = 0;
                    a++;
                }
                e++;
            }
            ofn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Ну гляньте сами - у вас же условие

```
if (num == 3)
```

находится в теле

```
if (num == 2)
```

Ну и как, если `num` равно 2, сможет быть истинным условие `num==3`?

К слову, и для 4 то же самое...

По-моему, вы пропустили одну закрывающую скобочку `}`, вернее, поставили ее не на свое место...